# Cargar archivo pdf a un jar compilado

Tags: java, pdf, maven, intellij-idea, itext

estoy intentando sacar ciertos datos de un pdf y guardarlos en una base de datos. La idea es que en mi programa cuando se apreta un botón, con selenium el programa descarga el pdf y lo carga al jar para poder leerlo.

Probe muchas librerías para leer pdfs pero todas se traban en el mismo lugar: cuando intento cargar el pdf.

Si compilo el programa en IntelliJ funciona perfecto, el problema esta cuando lo compilo a .jar. Se traba al cargar y no muestra ni un error. Intente de todo pero nada funciona.

Así esta mi código actualmente:

```
                try {

                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("out/artifacts/WAsNEWWINDOWS_jar/bills/facturaClaro.pdf");
                    System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");
                    String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);
                    System.out.println("Page Content:\n\n"+page+"\n\n");
                    System.out.println("Is this document tampered: "+reader.isTampered());
                    System.out.println("Is this document encrypted: "+reader.isEncrypted());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

El coding como esta funciona perfecto en IntelliJ, cuando lo compilo a .jar cambio la ubicación del archivo por:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("bills/facturaClaro.pdf");
```

Pero no parece funcionar y no me tira ni una excepción.

Cualquier aporte me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias!

UPDATE: aparentemento si estaba mostrando una excepción:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader
    at BillReader.readClaro(BillReader.java:195)
    at WebScrapper.startBillReaderClaro(WebScrapper.java:467)
    at Controller$20.call(Controller.java:4182)
    at Controller$20.call(Controller.java:4179)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Tengo correctamente todos las dependencias con maven no se que puede estar funcionando mal.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
       <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
       <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: libreria]

Comment: Hola Julia, me podrías aclarar un poco tu proceso, veo que estas hablando que con selenium acedes a una web a descarga un archivo pdf, al utilizar selenium este descarga el archivo a una ruta física como cualquier navegador no dentro de tu JAR, si ese es tu caso puedes definir en selenium una ruta de descarga  y buscar en esa ruta el PDF para procesarlo.

Comment: Hola @RobertoEMoran, gracias por tu respuesta! Si, luego de descargarlo lo copio en el directorio donde se encuentra el .jar. De todas formas, ahora para las pruebas no activo selenium, directamente coloque el pdf donde se encuentra el .jar para no tener que descargar cada vez que pruebo.

Comment: Realicé una prueba de ejecución y no me dio problemas, para estar seguro de la estructura deberías tener el jar de tu proyecto y en la misma carpeta una carpeta con el nombre bills y dentro de esta el archivo pdf. te dejo el link de la prueba https://github.com/remorandev/pdftest para ejecutarlo "java -jar Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" y dejo la el código de la clase que es muy simple, espero y te sirva de algo.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran , tengo cargado el la estructura exactamente como lo especificas, funciona cuando lo lee desde Intellij pero cuando lo abro en .jar. Estoy usando javafx y en la interfaz gráfica se aprieta el butano que acciona la carga y lectura del pdf. pero eso no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo!. Analize el .jar con el comando:

```
jar tvf WAsNEWWINDOWS.jar
```

y me pude dar cuenta que efectivamente, no estaba la clase necesaria. Como ya había visto las librerías en la estructura del proyecto en IntelliJ, mire los artefactos que extraía, y pude ver que no estaba el de iText, por lo tanto lo agregue como "extracted directory" y busqué donde estaba el .jar de iText y listo!. Compile de nuevo el jar y ya no me tira el error y funciona perfecto!. Dejo una imagen de donde agregue el .jar:
[image: extraer directorio]

Answer (score 0):

Con ese Error es mas fácil saber que sucede @Julia.

Te explico el error:

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader"

Eso quiere decir que al compilar tu jar este no incluye la dependencia ***itextpdf*** en el IDE funciona porque el IDE sabe agregar las dependencias para la ejecución, lo que debes hacer para comprobar que es ese tu caso con winrar abre el jar y dentro de este debe estar la carpeta lib con las dependencias o con las clases dentro de tu jar, para resolver el problema agrega esta configuración a tu POM:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>single</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                       <archive>
                           <manifest>
                     <!-- Aquí agrega el nombre con el paquete de tu clase main -->
                                 <mainClass>com.paquete.MainClass</mainClass>
                           </manifest>
                       </archive>
                       <descriptorRefs>
                           <!-- este es el sufijo que tendrá el jar con las librerías -->
                           <descriptorRef>jar-con-dependencias</descriptorRef>
                      </descriptorRefs>
                 </configuration>
         </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta. Como mi proyecto es una app javafxá no estoy muy sergura que clase agregar, pero probe muchas y sigue sin funcionar. De todas formas yo lo compilo con Intellij no con las herramientas de maven, esto funciona para este caso tambien? Gracias

Comment: No este solo funciona si usas Maven prueba con esta respuesta tiene las imágenes y los pasos  de como agregar las librerías: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta de nuevo, antes que me respondieras seguí esos pasos y agregue las librerías de iText como pedían. Actualice mi respuesta para mostrarlo, pero sigue sin funcionar.